# Enormous Increase In the Use Of Memory

Tags: c++, memory, recursion, tree

I've got a code where I need to create a map with key values as double (value of the f-test between two clusters. I need to calculate the residual sum of squares for this) and the mapped value of cluspair which is pair of the class Cluster that I created. Map aims to store the F-test values between the all clusters so that I would not need to do the calculation again and again in every step. BTW cluster is a tree structure where every cluster contains two subclusters and the stored values are 70-dimensional vectors.

Problem is, in order to calculate the RSS, I need to implement a recursive code where I need to find the distance of every element of the cluster with the mean of the cluster and this seems to be consuming an enormous amount of memory. When I create the same map with the key values being the simple distance between the means of two clusters, the program uses minimal memory so I think the increase in the memory use is caused by the call of the recursive function RSS. What should I do to manage the memory use in the code below? In its current implementation the system runs out of memory and windows closes the application saying that the system ran out of virtual memory.

The main code:

```
    map<double,cluspair> createRSSMap( list<Cluster*> cluslist )
    {
            list<Cluster*>::iterator it1;
            list<Cluster*>::iterator it2;

            map<double,cluspair> rtrnmap;


            for(it1=cluslist.begin(); it1!= --cluslist.end() ;it1++)
            {
                it2=it1;
                ++it2;
                cout << ".";

                list<Cluster*>::iterator itc;
                double cFvalue=10000000000000000000;
                double rIt1 = (*it1)->rss();

                for(int kk=0 ; it2!=cluslist.end(); it2++)
                {

                    Cluster tclustr ((*it1) , (*it2));
                    double r1 = tclustr.rss();
                    double r2= rIt1 + (*it2)->rss();
                    int df2 = tclustr.getNumOfVecs() - 2;

                    double fvalue = (r1 - r2) / (r2 / df2);

                    if(fvalue<cFvalue)
                    {
                        cFvalue=fvalue;
                        itc=it2;
                    }
                }


                cluspair clp;
                clp.c1 = *it1;
                clp.c2 = *itc;


                bool doesexists = (rtrnmap.find(cFvalue) != rtrnmap.end());

                while(rtrnmap)
                {
                    cFvalue+= 0.000000001;
                    rtrnmap= (rtrnmap.find(cFvalue) != rtrnmap.end());
                }

                rtrnmap[cFvalue] = clp;


            }

            return rtrnmap;
    }
```

and the imlementation of the function RSS:

```
double Cluster::rss()
{
    return rss(cnode->mean);
}

double Cluster::rss(vector<double> &cmean)
{
    if(cnode->numOfVecs==1)
    {
        return vectorDist(cmean,cnode->mean);
    }
    else
    {
        return ( ec1->rss(cmean) + ec2->rss(cmean) );       
    }
}
```

Much thanks in advance. I really don't know what to do at this point.

---

below is the code with that I use to create a map with keys being simple euclidian distance between two cluster means. As I've said above, it is quite similar and uses minimal memory. It only differs in the calculation of the fvalue. Instead of the recursive calculation, there is the calculation of simple distance of means of two clusters. Hope it helps to identify the problem

```
map<double,cluspair> createDistMap( list<Cluster*> cluslist )
{
        list<Cluster*>::iterator it1;
        list<Cluster*>::iterator it2;

        map<double,cluspair> rtrnmap;


        for(it1=cluslist.begin(); it1!= --cluslist.end() ;it1++)
        {
            it2=it1;
            ++it2;
            cout << ".";

            list<Cluster*>::iterator itc;
            double cDist=1000000000000000;

            for(int kk=0 ; it2!=cluslist.end(); it2++)
            {
                double nDist = vectorDist( (*it1)->getMean(),(*it2)->getMean());
                if (nDist<cDist)
                {
                    cDist = nDist;
                    itc=it2;
                }
            }   

            cluspair clp;
            clp.c1 = *it1;
          clp.c2 = *itc;



            bool doesexists = (rtrnmap.find(cDist) != rtrnmap.end());

            while(doesexists)
            {
                cDist+= 0.000000001;
                doesexists  = (rtrnmap.find(cDist) != rtrnmap.end());
            }

            rtrnmap[cDist] = clp;

        }

        return rtrnmap;
}
```

---

implementation of vectorDist()

```
double vectorDist(vector<double> vec1, vector<double> vec2)
{

    double sqrsum=0;
    double tempd=0;

    int vs = vec1.size();

    for ( int i=0;i<vs;i++)
    {
        tempd = vec1[i] - vec2[i];
        sqrsum += tempd*tempd;
    }

    return sqrsum;
}
```

**Edit:**

BTW I've tried this alternative implementation which still fails to control the memory usage

```
double Cluster::rss()
{
    list<double> fvals;
    rss(cnode->mean , fvals);

    double sum=0;
    list<double>::iterator tpit;
    for(tpit=fvals.begin() ; tpit != fvals.end() ; ++tpit)
    {
        sum += *tpit;
    }
    return sum;
}

void Cluster::rss(vector<double> &cmean , list<double> &fvals)
{
    if(cnode->numOfVecs==1)
    {
        fvals.push_back( vectorDist(cmean,cnode->mean) );
    }
    else
    {
        ec1->rss(cmean , fvals);
        ec2->rss(cmean , fvals);        
    }
}
```

Comment: tag it with a programming language

Comment: Is that while loop legal? Also, consider not returning a copy of a map<> but accepting it as a reference parameter

Comment: And how does Cluster::rss() "reduce" it's workload every iteration? Please post something that compiles first...

Comment: What do you mean with reducing its workload every iteration? The original code is quite extensive and has many steps. The function that I've quoted is the part I use to create a map of <double,cluspair> as I've mentioned.

Comment: btw I'm adding a similar function for creating a map with keys of simple distances instead of the f-test calculation. it is quite similar and differs in the part that I've said and it uses quite minimal memory. Hope it helps to identify the problem

Comment: @serkank : A recursive function (like your rss) need a termination condition (which you have) and a way to decompose the problem into smaller problems (which are solvable by your terminating condition).

Comment: @serkank - you are passing `cluslist` by value to `cluslist` and `createRSSMap`, it would be more memory efficient to pass it as a reference (`const list<Cluster*>&`).  Although that would only have much of an effect if `cluslist` is a _huge_ list.

Comment: @Andrei if you look at the implementation of the function rss, the part "return ( ec1->rss(cmean) + ec2->rss(cmean) )" decomposes the problem into smaller problems. Cluster is a tree structure and contains two subclusters, which are ec1 and ec2. I'm calculating the RSS of the subclusters and finding the sum of them which would be the RSS of the cluster that contains them

Comment: @Node list is quite huge, I think what you said can have an effect. I'm changing that part now. Much thanks for the input. But I don't think that that's the main problem. The other code, that I've written at the end, has the same implementation but is running with a quite low memory.

Comment: @serkank - what does the code for `vectorDist` look like?

Comment: @Node double vectorDist(vector<double> vec1, vector<double> vec2)
{
 
 double sqrsum=0;
 double tempd=0;

 int vs = vec1.size();

 for ( int i=0;i<vs;i++)
 {
  tempd = vec1[i] - vec2[i];
  sqrsum += tempd*tempd;
 }
 
 return sqrsum;
}

Comment: @Node I've also added it to my first post in order to format it

Comment: @serkank - Im not sure why it would run out of memory...out of interest, do you know how many recursive calls to `rss` there are?

Comment: there are approximately 14000 objects in the completed tree, so there would be quite a lot of calls

Comment: @serkank - try putting a `static int` counter into `rss` to check, it could be too many calls and blowing the stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running out of memory you have a very deep tree or your Cluster objects are large or both.  Try creating another tree data structure of doubles with the same topology as your Cluster tree and call it RSS tree to hold the RSS values.  Calculate the bottom nodes' rss values and then recursively fill out the rest of the values *in the RSS tree*.  This way you aren't holding the cluster objects in memory while you do the rss calculation.

Comment: Cluster tree is both large and deep I'm afraid :) I see what you mean, I haven't thought that the cluster objects were being kept in the memory till the end of calculation. I'll give it a try but I'm still not sure about it. I'm returning the results of the calculation that I've done with the objects. Are the objects themselves are kept in the memory too?

Comment: Each recursive call to rss is storing the member variables from the Cluster object that is calling it on the stack before putting a new Cluster::rss call on the call stack.  If you are 100 levels deep in the tree you are going to be holding as many as 300 Cluster objects in memory in the call stack from the upper recursive calls, (since each Cluster object has a pair of cluster objects as members) plus whatever other member data the Cluster object has.  When you call a function, in general you hold the local data on the stack until it returns.

Comment: But wouldn't it cause the same problem with depth to calculate the rss of bottom nodes? In order to reach the bottom nodes I would still have to store previous cluster objects.

Comment: Not necessarily.  You want to do a depth-first search through the tree, when you hit a node which has both children nodes empty, put the rss of that node in the rss tree and continue.  You can maintain a stack of pointers or references to cluster objects that you still have to explore as you search the tree so that the memory use is limited to the one cluster node you are looking at plus the stack of pointers to cluster objects you still have to explore.  More detailed information on depth-first searches can be found on wikipedia or better yet an algorithms text.