# memory use in recursive tree algorithm

Tags: c++, memory, recursion, tree

I've got a code where I need to create a map with key values as double (value of the f-test between two clusters. I need to calculate the residual sum of squares for this) and the mapped value of cluspair which is pair of the class Cluster that I created. Map aims to store the F-test values between the all clusters so that I would not need to do the calculation again and again in every step. BTW cluster is a tree structure where every cluster contains two subclusters and the stored values are 70-dimensional vectors.

Problem is, in order to calculate the RSS, I need to implement a recursive code where I need to find the distance of every element of the cluster with the mean of the cluster and this seems to be consuming an enormous amount of memory. When I create the same map with the key values being the simple distance between the means of two clusters, the program uses minimal memory so I think the increase in the memory use is caused by the call of the recursive function RSS. What should I do to manage the memory use in the code below? In its current implementation the system runs out of memory and windows closes the application saying that the system ran out of virtual memory.

The main code:

```
    map<double,cluspair> createRSSMap( list<Cluster*> cluslist )
    {
            list<Cluster*>::iterator it1;
            list<Cluster*>::iterator it2;

            map<double,cluspair> rtrnmap;


            for(it1=cluslist.begin(); it1!= --cluslist.end() ;it1++)
            {
                it2=it1;
                ++it2;
                cout << ".";

                list<Cluster*>::iterator itc;
                double cFvalue=10000000000000000000;
                double rIt1 = (*it1)->rss();

                for(int kk=0 ; it2!=cluslist.end(); it2++)
                {

                    Cluster tclustr ((*it1) , (*it2));
                    double r1 = tclustr.rss();
                    double r2= rIt1 + (*it2)->rss();
                    int df2 = tclustr.getNumOfVecs() - 2;

                    double fvalue = (r1 - r2) / (r2 / df2);

                    if(fvalue<cFvalue)
                    {
                        cFvalue=fvalue;
                        itc=it2;
                    }
                }


                cluspair clp;
                clp.c1 = *it1;
                clp.c2 = *itc;


                bool doesexists = (rtrnmap.find(cFvalue) != rtrnmap.end());

                while(rtrnmap)
                {
                    cFvalue+= 0.000000001;
                    rtrnmap= (rtrnmap.find(cFvalue) != rtrnmap.end());
                }

                rtrnmap[cFvalue] = clp;


            }

            return rtrnmap;
    }
```

and the imlementation of the function RSS:

```
double Cluster::rss()
{
    return rss(cnode->mean);
}

double Cluster::rss(vector<double> &cmean)
{
    if(cnode->numOfVecs==1)
    {
        return vectorDist(cmean,cnode->mean);
    }
    else
    {
        return ( ec1->rss(cmean) + ec2->rss(cmean) );       
    }
}
```

Much thanks in advance. I really don't know what to do at this point.

---

below is the code with that I use to create a map with keys being simple euclidian distance between two cluster means. As I've said above, it is quite similar and uses minimal memory. It only differs in the calculation of the fvalue. Instead of the recursive calculation, there is the calculation of simple distance of means of two clusters. Hope it helps to identify the problem

```
    map<double,cluspair> createDistMap( list<Cluster*> cluslist )
    {
            list<Cluster*>::iterator it1;
            list<Cluster*>::iterator it2;

            map<double,cluspair> rtrnmap;


            for(it1=cluslist.begin(); it1!= --cluslist.end() ;it1++)
            {
                it2=it1;
                ++it2;
                cout << ".";

                list<Cluster*>::iterator itc;
                double cDist=1000000000000000;

                for(int kk=0 ; it2!=cluslist.end(); it2++)
                {
                    double nDist = vectorDist( (*it1)->getMean(),(*it2)->getMean());
                    if (nDist<cDist)
                    {
                        cDist = nDist;
                        itc=it2;
                    }
                }   

                cluspair clp;
                clp.c1 = *it1;
              clp.c2 = *itc;



                bool doesexists = (rtrnmap.find(cDist) != rtrnmap.end());

                while(doesexists)
                {
                    cDist+= 0.000000001;
                    doesexists  = (rtrnmap.find(cDist) != rtrnmap.end());
                }

                rtrnmap[cDist] = clp;

            }

            return rtrnmap;
    }
```

---

Cluster constructer

```
Cluster::Cluster (Cluster *C1, Cluster *C2)
{
    ec1=C1;
    ec2=C2;
    node* cn = new node;
    cn->numOfVecs = C1->cnode->numOfVecs + C2->cnode->numOfVecs;

    double nov = cn->numOfVecs;
    double div = (1 / nov);

    cn->mean = scalarMultVect(div,vectAdd(scalarMultVect(C1->cnode->numOfVecs,C1->cnode->mean),scalarMultVect(C2->cnode->numOfVecs,C2->cnode->mean)));

    mvect tmv;
    tmv.stock="";
    cn->v1 = tmv;

    cnode = cn;
}
```

Comment: You haven't given us enough code to reproduce the problem, but it looks as if you could save a lot of calculation (and maybe memory) by *storing* these RSS values and not recomputing them so many times.

Comment: the loop is for finding the fvalues between cluster pairs. when the loop is at the last element, there is no cluster to find the fvalue for after that point.

Comment: Does the `Cluster::Cluster(const Cluster* pc1, const Cluster* pc2)` constructor do a deep copy of the entire tree nodes of the two input clusters? Please explain its memory usage, and/or post the constructor's code.

Comment: @Beta vectorDist is the euclidian distance between two mean vectors. ec1 and ec2 are the two subclusters. and the cnode->mean gives the mean of the current cluster. if you to know anything else I would gladly give more code but just didn't want to fill the page with unnecessary codes. As for the storing RSS values, this is a tree is building process and therefore RSS values wouldn't stay same and it would change with the means of the new parent clusters.

Comment: @Beta and @aristos: the RSS values of a single cluster (the `r2`) can be precomputed. But I think the RSS values of a combination of clusters will have to be computed recursively.

Comment: @rwong I've added the code of the constructer but it basicly referances to the subclusters. Doesn't do a deep copy. Btw you are right about r2, they can be precomputed and stored but this is not the part of the big problem. I could ignore the extra cost of calculating the rss of r2 twice. But I don't know how to resolve the memory issue in the call of the function RSS

Comment: @aristos: is there a memory leak in the `vectorDist` function? To test it, just create two double vectors, and then call `vectorDist` millions of times (I'd suggest calling it 100,000,000 times) and see if memory usage goes up or crashes. Otherwise, I couldn't find any place in your code which would create temporary objects or consume large memory. (aside from the `node` and `mvect` which were members of the temporary `Cluster`)

Comment: @rwong no memory leak in the vectorDist function i'm afraid

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enormous Increase In the Use Of Memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394984/enormous-increase-in-the-use-of-memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked exactly the same question before:
 [Enormous Increase In the Use Of Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394984/enormous-increase-in-the-use-of-memory)

1. rtrnmap= (rtrnmap.find(cFvalue) != rtrnmap.end()); does not make sense.
2. You were told to pass data through references
3. You were told to add logging information and see how many iterations are performed.

A few comments:

- It is a bad idea to have a `map` with a `double` as key as you may find yourself unable to retrieve an element due to a tiny difference in the `double`.
- Add only a few elements in the collection and manually go through all the functions in the debugger. You'll get to "see" what gets executed and can immediately see if the actual execution flow matches your expectations

And please don't double post your questions (even if you use different users).

EDIT:

We all assumed a proper destructor. Make sure you deallocate any memory you explicitly allocate with `new` or `new[]` with `delete` or `delete[]` as appropriate.

Comment: Sorry for that, just thought that the old post would go unseen. doesexists = (rtrnmap.find(cDist) != rtrnmap.end()) would return true if map contains an element with the same key that is wanted to be added. In that case, a tiny amount of 0.00000001 will be added and thereby no info would be lost. Counter would give a value with maximum of 2 to the power 14000. I'm aware that this is a huge number but that is the nature of the data I have to deal with. Tree is quite large.

Comment: @aristos : You have a limited amount of stack space for the recursion (and your function is not tail call optimisable).

Comment: @aristos : are you sure you know what 2 to the poser 14000 means?

Comment: And what do you mean "no info will be lost"? You do realize that "rtrnmap[cDist] = clp;" will add a new element in the rtrnmap every time it is called, right? (Because of the loop above which finds a cDist not in the map)

Comment: @andrei Well I have about 14k vectors to build a cluster tree from. 2 to the power 14000 minus one would be equal to the number of recursions. Is there no way to make an optimisation for that kind of problem? By "no info will be lost" I meant that there would be no overwriting. If the given key is already in the map, while loop would find a double value close to cDist which is not a key of the map.

Comment: @andrei btw two to the power 14000 is the maximum number of recursions in the cluster problem. I guess it is around 2 to the power 1000 though

Comment: @aristos : I think you might need to change the algorithm you use and make some optimisations at that level. Can you please detail the algorithm you use or post a link to a reference?

Comment: @andrei This algorithm is used where I need to build a clustering tree from the input vectors. In every step, the main algoritm pairs the two clusters with the minimum fvalues inbetween. Therefore I need to find the fvalues of all possible cluster pairs. I can't proceed unless the those rss calculations have been made, therefore this process is not avoidable. Any optimisation I made should be in this algorithm, I'm afraid I can't avoid to use this function and do it another way.

Comment: @aristos : Examine the destructor for the Cluster, see if you delete cn. Test each of the functions you have with SMALL inputs and see if one of them leaks.

Comment: @andrei That might be the problem I guess. I'm new to c++ and don't really know how to use deconstructers. When I encountered some problems, I just deleted the whole deconstructer part and it was ok when I used the code with relatively small data so I haven't thought about it again. Now I've placed a deconstructer which deletes everything but then the program don't run properly and closes itself. What should I delete in the deconstructer. There is cnode (which contains the mean data), ec1 and ec2(which are the subclusters)

Comment: @aristos : delete anything you allocate with new, in this case "cn"